# DocuSign: Unable to set the email for a CC role upon creating an envelope from a template using the REST API

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to dynamically populate a non-signer CC role upon creating an envelope from a template using the REST API. Is this possible? Currently, when I add the "receive a copy" recipient role to a template and then set the email for that roleName in the code and send the document off for signing, it automatically "completes" the document which seems like a bug or it may be that I'm doing something that isn't supported? Can anyone help?

Thanks,

Janea

Comment: Are you creating a draft envelope from a template first, then adding the CC recipient later and sending, or are you adding your 1 signer and 1 CC recipient when you create the envelope and sending all with one API call?

Comment: I've tried doing it both ways. When I set the CC recipient upon creating the envelope using one call, that's when it auto "completes" the document. However, when I attempt to add the CC recipient later, I run into a host of other issues. Mainly, it just doesn't work and the most common error is "invalid content" but the content is valid. So, either way I am running into issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Carbon copy recipients](http://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/recipients) are unique in that that is the only recipient type that does not take any actions on the envelope.  They simply receive a copy of the envelope when it's their turn in the routing order, they never see the "tagging" workflow (unless they are added as another signing recipient on the envelope at the same or a different routing order).

When you have a CC recipient and it is their turn in the routing order, nothing happens except that they receive the notification email.  If they have the highest routing order out of all recipients (i.e. if they are the last recipient) then the envelope status will already be **completed** by the time it reaches them and it won't change status and will remain as complete.

Comment: Ergin, that doesn't seem to apply in this scenario. The signer doesn't even have the opportunity to sign the document. As soon as it is sent it marked "complete", even though the CC recipient is at the bottom of the routing order. Which according to the documentation is the way it should be set up. The document should never get to that place in the routing order until the document has been signed.

Comment: How is your envelope setup in terms of recipient types and routing orders?  Please explain how many recipients of type "Signer" you have, how many "CC" recipients, and in what routing order everybody is in.  From my tests everything is working as designed currently.  And as an FYI, you can have a CC recipient anywhere in the routing order - they don't have to be at the end.  --Ergin

Comment: There is one Signer and one CC. The signer is routing order 1. The CC is routing order 2.

Comment: Well either you're not describing the situation clearly or I'm not understanding you but I keep testing this and it works just fine for me.  I've got a template with 2 roles on it, routing order 1 and 2.  The first role is a Signer role and the second is "Receives A Copy" (i.e. CC recipient).  I send a REST API request using the template and the first gets the envelope and signs, then the CC recipient is notified...

Comment: What is the REST API call you're using? Also, are you saying that once you create the envelope using the template then receive the notification to sign the envelope, you then go to the envelope, then sign it and upon completing the envelope the CC recipient is notified?

Comment: I just want to clarify those are the steps you are following since, what I'm seeing is that as soon as you send the envelope using the REST API call, it automatically "completes" the envelope without me actually going in and signing it. So, upon 'sending for signing', it automatically signs it and the CC recipient is notified...that is clarification for you on the behavior that I am seeing.

Comment: The REST API call I'm making is [request a signature from template](http://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Send%20an%20Envelope%20from%20a%20Template.htm) and yes, I receive the notification to sign, I go in and sign, and upon completing the CC gets notified.  I'm thinking there's some other issue going on with how you are configuring your envelope.  This is working fine for me and no other devs are reporting issues with CCs

Comment: Ergin, thanks for all your help. I went back and implemented the same exact solution as before...the one that was "auto completing documents upon sending for signature" and it is no longer behaving that way. It's a mystery why it was doing that to begin with, but it seems to be working fine now. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok cool, not sure what was going on before but glad it's working now.  Might have been a bug.  In any case, can you accept my answer when you get a chance?  Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Ergin was correct. Using the API call to add the CC role as the envelope is created from the template works as expected. It did not seem to work initially but, not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Are there other recipients? If there's only a single recipient and they are marked as "receive a copy" or "CarbonCopy", and not marked as a "Signer" type, it will probably see the envelope as complete.

Comment: There are other signers yes. The "CarbonCopy" signer is the last one in the list of "signers".